# Connection Refused (GRE Tunnel - FiveM)

Tags: networking, iptables, gre, connection-refused, gameserver

I am running a game server using Vultr. What I am trying to do is run the game server (backend server) through a GRE Tunnel. For this, I am using x4b.net for my GRE Tunnel. A few things to note:

The guide that I used is listed here: https://www.x4b.net/kb/Tutorials/FiveMDDoSProtection

The port that I am using for my game server is 2002. I have created firewall rules to allow traffic through that port.

Per x4b support this was their reply:

`Having bound your service to the tunnel it is expected that the service will no longer be accessible on the backend ip of your server. This is normally desired by most people.`

`Its outside the scope of what most customers do (therefore you may need to investigate for any binding related issues) but you can look into binding to 0.0.0.0 (every IP on your system). This may however introduce IP leaks and other compatibility issues in some services.` **How would I even do this? Would that work?**

Now, my server is seeing the service running from the tunnel IP address, but for some reason the connection is still being refused. I have 10.16.2.6    Bound via NAT to 103.77.224.85 and am using 10.16.2.6 as my listen IP address, not 0.0.0.0. I set this in the server.cfg as per the guide from x4b.

How do I get the server to not refuse connections? See gyazo screenshots below.

https://gyazo.com/31387e42252b72f84567102aa2e64952

https://gyazo.com/ebc73666f998b2c36b5ead3b719d8ebf

https://gyazo.com/532f940631f6d1c01d7ab12300c81221

Thanks to anyone who can help.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved with this post! Hope it helps others.

https://forum.cfx.re/t/help-gre-tunnel-reverse-proxy-setup-curl-7-refusing-connection/4872661